# How to sort an array without destroying the original array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have original array of

```
public static void main (String[] arg) {
  int[] array = {1,5,6,8,4,2}

  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("List 1 = " + array[i] + ",");
  }
  swap(array);
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("List 2 = "+array[i] + ",");
  }
}
private static int swap (int[] list){
   Arrays.sort(list);
}
```

The output is

```
 List 1 = 1,5,6,8,4,2
 List 2 = 1,2,4,5,6,8
```

What I want the answer to be is

```
List 1 = 1,5,6,8,4,2
List 2 = 1,5,6,8,4,2
```

even after sorting. How can I do it?

Comment: But if shows the same after sorting is not sorting at all...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
int[] originalArray = {1,5,6,8,4,2};
int[] backup = Arrays.copyOf(originalArray,originalArray.length);
Arrays.sort(backup);
```

After the execution of the code above, `backup` becomes sorted and `originalArray` stays same.

Comment: IF so, How can i pass that sorted array to another method?

Comment: @userpane are you kidding? you can just call something like _yourMethod(backup);_

Comment: No no... I know that but It is in non-main method so I could not pass it to another non-main method.

Comment: you can return it. example: `public int[] yourMethod() { //some other code return backup; }`